# Error while converting the following StreamReader result to XML ín C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing

```
  if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {

                        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {

                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                res= reader.ReadToEnd();
                                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                                doc.XmlResolver = null;
                                doc.Load(res);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(res);
                        }

                    }
```

In above code, I'm getting following result in res variable.

How to get TID attribute from given result.

```
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "http://today.com/email/viewemail.dtd">
<RESULT REQID="16006914462">
   <MID SUBMITDATE="2018-08-02 12:25:37" ID="1" TAG="null" TID="40293189378" />
</RESULT>
```

When i try to convert above result in `XmlDocument` it throw the exception like

Illegal characters in path.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are creating the XmlDocument?

Comment: @mnieto code updated

Comment: what do you mean with "try to convert above result in XmlDocument"? you're getting exception on `doc.Load(html)`?

Comment: @Nino Yes . excpetion Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.

Comment: @MannanBahelim try to set `doc.XmlResolver = null` before `doc.Load(html);`

Comment: You mention a `res` variable. Where is it?
I tried to load your xml within a XmlDocument and it works correctly: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pCKfup

Comment: @Nino code upldated

Comment: @mnieto res variable is global so not mention it in code sample

Comment: @mnieto thanks. its workingg...woow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns a string. `XmlDocument.Load` loads content from a file or a stream.

So you should to use

```
   doc.LoadXml(res);
```

Or you can modify your code to load de XmlDocument from the stream

```
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(reader);
                            doc.XmlResolver = null;
                            doc.Load(res);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(res);
                    }
```

Comment: How do I get the TID from doc  variable ?

Comment: You can use Linq to xml as @Wheels73 sugested. Don't forget to add the `using 
 System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: @MannanBahelim if you're usinx `XmlDocument`, you can fetch it using `XPath`, like this: `var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("*/MID[1]/@TID");` and if `nodes.Count > 0` the you can find TID value in `nodes[0].Values`

Answer (score 2):

You could use LinqXMl to do what you need also. In the below example I load the xml from a text file to simulate the xml response. There is an overload on the XDocument.Load method that takes an XML string.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");
XElement resultNode = xdoc.Elements().First().Elements().FirstOrDefault();
var tidVale = resultNode.Attributes().First(a => a.Name == "TID");
```

You can then access the attributes accordingly.

Hope that helps